# ¿Como puedo activar un checkbox con un button?

Tags: javascript, html5, botón, checkbox

tengo un formulario html5 con un botón, al pulsarlo se abre una nueva ventana a parte, lo que me gustaría hacer es que al pulsar el botón se marque una checkbox oculta.
Lo he intentado con una label, pero si la label envuelve el "button" y el enlace ("a") el button abre la ventana nueva pero no marca la checkbox, y si envuelve solo el button y no el enlace ("a") marca el checkbox pero no abre la ventana nueva.

El código que comparto actualmente abre la ventana nueva pero no marca la checkbox.

El checkbox sirve para saber si ha pulsado el button.

No se mucho de Javascript, suelo usar php pero acepto cualquier ayuda. ;)

PD: Este es mi primer post, no se si tendría que dar más datos.

```
<form>

    <label for="me_pulso">

        <a href="javascript:if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1) 
        {location='';}if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') != -1){window.open('
        <?php echo $_SESSION["URL"]; ?>
        ','','width=950,height=900,left=0,top=0,toolbar=yes');};void 0">

             <button type="button">Mostrar página</button>
        </a>

    </label>

    <input id="me_pulso" name="me_pulso" type="checkbox" value="1">

</form>
```

Solucionado, gracias por la ayuda.

```
<script>

    function abrirPagina(){

        if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1) {

            location='';
    }

    if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') != -1){

        window.open('<?php echo $_SESSION["url"]; ?>','','width=950,height=900,left=0,top=0,toolbar=yes');
    }

    document.getElementById('me_pulso').checked = true;
}

</script>

<button type="button" onclick="abrirPagina()">Mostrar página</button>
<input id="me_pulso" name="me_pulso" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es buena idea utilizar un `<a>` para la acción del botón. Puedes poner una función que realice las dos tareas (abrir ventana y marcar el checkbox). Mejor utilizar el método `onclick` del botón que llame a la función.

```
<script>
    function abrirPagina(){
        if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Microsoft Internet Explorer') != -1) {
            location='';
        }
        if(navigator.appName.indexOf('Netscape') != -1){
            window.open('<?php echo $_SESSION["URL"]; ?>
                ','','width=950,height=900,left=0,top=0,toolbar=yes');
        }
        document.getElementById('me_pulso').checked = true;
    }
</script>
<form>
  <button type="button" onclick="abrirPagina()">Mostrar página</button>
  <input id="me_pulso" name="me_pulso" type="checkbox" value="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

con javascript puedes cambiar el estado del checkbox con true o false.
querySelector te permite especificar que elemento quieres y onclick es el evento de hacer click.

```
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {       
 document.querySelector("#me_pulso").checked = true;
}
```